# Quick way to remove a column(s) from every data.table in a list of data.tables R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, dplyr, purrr

I have a list of data.tables and I would like to remove columns from all of the data.tables. I could not get `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` to work and the one solution I came up with was a bit slow:

```
x <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","c"), j = 1:3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y <- data.frame(id = c("b","c","d"), k = 4:6, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
z <- data.frame(id = c("c","d","a"), l = 7:9, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df.list <- list(x,y,z)

for (i in 1:length(df.list)) {
    df.list[[i]] <- df.list[[i]] %>% dplyr::select(-id)
}
```

Simple one, thank you!

Comment: What you have created _here_ is a `list` of vectors, not a list of frames/tables. If you meant to instead do `df.list <- list(x,y,z)`, then `lapply(df.list, select, -id)` does what you want.

Comment: Made the update, thanks. Ok yes, thank you for making me realize that arguments passed after ```FUN``` would be taken as optional arguments to ```FUN``` (unless they are specified as another argument modifying the behavior of ```lapply```).

Comment: `map(df.list, ~select(.x, -id))`

Comment: what does that tilda denote? sorry. @MAurélio

Comment: Recent documentation suggests not to use optional arguments in `map(...)`, they must be explicitly passed in an anonymous function, that's what the "~" does, its the same as `function(x) select(x, -id)`